# Android java read html content

Tags: java, android, url

I have a problem with this code to display the html content. When I try it on your smartphone, I would print "Error" that is capturing an error, where am I wrong?

```
String a2="";   
try {
    URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
    InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        a2+=inputLine;
    }
    in.close();
    tx.setText("OUTPUT \n"+a2);

} catch (Exception e) {  
    tx.setText("Error");    
}
```

Comment: ... How about you tell us what the exception is?

Answer (score 0):

[URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) requires a correctly formed url. You should use:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
```

Update:

As you are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, it appears that you are attempting to make the connection in the main thread.

Ths solution is to run the code in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: It is necessary to have this format. You may be encountering another problem. Add `tx.setText("Error " + e);`

Comment: I solved it by adding this code: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);